# Aligning Button to Bottom of Screen

Tags: android, android-layout

I have looked at a lot of answers and not found one that isn't a work-around. So, excuse me if this has been asked and answered.

I have a `RelativeLayout` that I want to appear at the bottom of the screen regardless of the size of the stuff outside the `RelativeLayout` and above it. Can this work as designed (`Relative` below `Relative`)? If so, please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Note: I have removed most of the guts that make it obvious why the first `RelativeLayout` has to be a `RelativeLayout` and the 2nd `RelativeLayout` is usually an `<include...` that I use in other places and put in explicitly for this example.

Thanks.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/enter_Game_Name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:hint="Enter Game Name"
        android:inputType="text" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/d_cancel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="@android:string/cancel" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here's what I get...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second **RelativeLayout** you have `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` , this attribute will not work because the parent is a **LinearLayout** where this attribute doesn't work and has no effect, make you parent layout RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout and remove the Orientation attribute since it will has no effect, then you will get the button at the bottom of the screen no matter the size of the screen and layout above your **Button**

Comment: It worked. Thanks. Can you explain why `layout_align_ParentBottom` is not appropriate for a `LinearLayout`?

Comment: Linear layout works as if it puts its children as they are blocks ( horizontally or vertically ) as you specify in the orientation attribute. you specified the orientation as vertical and your button is the last element so it will positioned always after the last element regardles the end of the linear layout.

Answer (score 0):

You parent layout is a linear layout. Make it a Relative layout. Then Put two Views (Edit Text and Button) in it and set one to align top and one to align bottom.

Your code would look like something like this (not tested)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >


<EditText
        android:id="@+id/enter_Game_Name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:hint="Enter Game Name"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

        android:inputType="text" />

<Button
        android:id="@+id/d_cancel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="@android:string/cancel" />
</RelativeLayout>
```